# Why isn't exemplar created in windows.onload event handler globally visible?

Tags: javascript

Sorry in advance if I misused some terms or definitions.
 Example:

```
class First  {
    constructor(){
        this.value = 5;
    }
}

class Second {
    constructor(){
        this.value = testFirst.value
    }
}


window.onload = function(){

const testFirst = new First();
const testSecond = new Second(); // testFirst is not defined
}
```

I thought that if the scope for `window.onload` event is `window`, and variable, declared with `var` stays after function execution, then `testFirst` should be accessible from basically everywhere. What is the problem here?

Comment: `testFirst` is contestual (scoped) to the function block. That doesn't, however, implicitely make it global and neither available on `window`. You probably wanted an **implicit global** instead. https://jsfiddle.net/e31wc7z9/ . If you want to make it available to `window`, you should use the onload's `this` instead (if you don't want to use the implicit global way): https://jsfiddle.net/e31wc7z9/1/

Comment: You may want to play with variables a bit, take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e31wc7z9/2/

Answer (score 3):

No, because you are defining the `testFirst` and `testSecond` variables inside of an anonymous function and only in that function that is possible to access to thoose variables.

In order to access globally, you could do something like this:

```
var testFirst;
var testSecond;

window.onload = function(){

    testFirst = new First();
    testSecond = new Second();
}
```

or

```
window.onload = function(){

    window.testFirst= new First();
    window.testSecond = new Second();
}
```

Specifically, for your case, follows a working script for the first example:

```js
var testFirst;
var testSecond;

class First  {
    constructor(){
        this.value = 5;
    }
}

class Second {
    constructor(){
        this.value = testFirst.value
    }
}


window.onload = function(){
   testFirst = new First();
   testSecond = new Second(); // testFirst is not defined
   console.log(testSecond.value);
}
```

And for the second case:

```js
class First  {
    constructor(){
        this.value = 5;
    }
}

class Second {
    constructor(){
        this.value = window.testFirst.value
    }
}


window.onload = function(){
   window.testFirst = new First();
   window.testSecond = new Second(); // testFirst is not defined
   console.log(testSecond.value);
}
```

Also, if you define a variable without a var, let your const tag, the variable will become globally as well:

```js
class First  {
    constructor(){
        this.value = 5;
    }
}

class Second {
    constructor(){
        this.value = testFirst.value
    }
}


window.onload = function(){
   testFirst = new First();
   testSecond = new Second(); // testFirst is not defined
   console.log(testSecond.value);
}
```

Comment: And this is why if I change `this.value = 5;` to `value = 5;` it will make `value` property a private one, right? Because it exists in the constructor, but doesn't get assignet to anything else?

Comment: No, if you don't declare the make value = 5; the value variable became global

Comment: I will put another example on my answer for you to understand better

Comment: @IgorCheglakov changing `this.value = 5` to `value = 5` will raise a **ReferenceError** in a class constructor at runtime, unless `value` is **declared globally**.

Answer (score 1):

Because `const` is scoped. It does not exist before declaration. Consider this an example:

```js
console.log(value);
var value = 42;

/**
 *JavaScript engine must "hoist" that `var` declaration to top of file, so it ends up being:
 
 var value;
 console.log(value);
 value = 42
  */
```

With const, it doesn't happen:

```js
console.log(value);
const value = 42; // No "hoisting"
```

---

Now, here's another example.

```js
function logValue() {
  console.log(value);
}

const value = 42;
logValue();
```

What happened there:
A function was declared.
A `value` was created *on global scope*.
We called the function - it found the value in the global scope.

---

Let's work with your version now:

```js
function logValue() {
  console.log(value);
}

function run(){
  const value = 42;
  // testFirst now exists _but only in the scope of the run function!
  // logValue is not in that scope!
  logValue();
}

run();
```

Finally, let's try something else:

```js
function run(){
  function logValue() {
    console.log(value);
  }
  const value = 42;
  // testFirst now exists _but only in the scope of the run function!
  // logValue is not in that scope!
  logValue();
}

run();
```

Now the function was in the same scope. So if you move your classes into the same onLoad function in which you create instances, it will work.

Comment: _With a var it is not the case._ That's not true. Onload has its own scope, replacing `const` with `var` **won't** make it available globally.

Comment: You're right, I should point out that it doesnt apply _here_. Lemme see how I can rephrase the thing.